# Maximum allowed adsense ads in a webpage

Tags: google-adsense

I know that we can display maximum three standard adsense ads in a web page.

I'm already using the following ad sizes in my website.

1. 728 x 90 - Image ad
2. 250 x 250 - Image ad
3. 300 x 250 - Image ad

But can I display an additional 728 x 15 `link unit`. If yes how many link units can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AdSense for content**: Up to three ad units and three link units may be placed on each page.

Read up on current [AdSense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182)